# Ошибка в построении блоков в ряд

Tags: html, css

Есть 3 блока, нужно разместить их горизонтально в ряд.
Знаю, что можно и по-другому, но хотелось бы понять почему не получается так.
  Так же если раскомментить последнее правило в `CSS`, то все 3 столбца перемещаются вправо, а не последний. `Display block` убирала, тоже не помогло.
  Была бы благодарна, если кто-нибудь более подробно объяснить в чем суть `display: block;`

```css
.sec2 {
  height: 285px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.icons {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 320px;
  display: block;
}

.ic {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.container h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.container p {
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
}


/*.icons:last-child {*/

float: right;

}
```

```html
<section class="sec2 clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="icons">

      <div>
        <img src="img/icon1.png" class="ic">
        <h1> Гибкий график обучения</h1>
        <p>Современный темп жизни требует гибкого подхода к расписанию.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="img/icon2.png" class="ic">
        <h1>Практические занятия</h1>
        <p>
          На одной теории далеко не уедешь, поэтому мы обучаем на практике.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="img/icon3.png" class="ic">
        <h1>Не оставим без работы</h1>
        <p>
          Хорошие специалисты всегда в цене и Вы станете именно таким.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Все в этом мире имеет свой размер, и `html` элементы тем более, да еще и блочные. Если им не задавать ширину, то они занимают всю ширину родителя. Блочным элементам надо было задать ширину и `float:left;` или `display: inline-block` тоже с шириной, и  без  `float:left;`

```css
.sec2 {
  height: 285px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.icons {
  text-align: center;
  width: 320px;
  display: block;
}

.ic {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.container h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.container p {
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
}

.iconsChild {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec2 clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="icons">

      <div class="iconsChild">
        <img src="img/icon1.png" class="ic">
        <h1> Гибкий график обучения</h1>
        <p>Современный темп жизни требует гибкого подхода к расписанию.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="iconsChild">
        <img src="img/icon2.png" class="ic">
        <h1>Практические занятия</h1>
        <p>
          На одной теории далеко не уедешь, поэтому мы обучаем на практике.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="iconsChild">
        <img src="img/icon3.png" class="ic">
        <h1>Не оставим без работы</h1>
        <p>
          Хорошие специалисты всегда в цене и Вы станете именно таким.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```